# Degree Distribution for directed graph

Tags: python, csv, graph, jupyter-notebook

When trying to create a graph for Kin and Kout I got a wrong graph.
I need to create use the histogram function
For now, I got to this part of code :

```
def plot_degree_In(G):
    in_degrees = G.in_degree()
    in_degrees=dict(in_degrees)
    in_values = sorted(set(in_degrees.values()))
    in_hist = [list(in_degrees.values()).count(x) for x in in_values]

plt.figure() 
plt.grid(False)
plt.loglog(in_values, in_hist, 'r.') 
#plt.loglog(out_values, out_hist, 'b.') 
#plt.legend(['In-degree', 'Out-degree'])
plt.xlabel('k')
plt.ylabel('p(k)')
plt.title('Degree Distribution')
plt.xlim([0, 2*100**1])
```

I also tried to use this part, but my network is connected

```
def plot_degree_dist(G):
    degree_hist = nx.degree_histogram(G) 
    degree_hist = np.array(degree_hist, dtype=float)
    degree_prob = degree_hist/G.number_of_nodes()
    plt.loglog(np.arange(degree_prob.shape[0]),degree_prob,'b.')
    plt.xlabel('k')
    plt.ylabel('p(k)')
    plt.title('Degree Distribution')
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Hi Amit! Can you clarify your question. How is your graph wrong? Do you need help using the Histogram function? Its a little unclear at the moment.

Comment: Hey, I can't share the graph but the main thing is that I need help with the Histogram function...

Comment: How can I make k vs p(k) in directed gragh by using an Histogram